# Can I configure Mission Control so any space can be summoned on any monitor?

Tags: macos, spaces, mission-control

I'm new to Mac and trying to get dual display spaces to behave like my previous system.

It seems like my choices are to have up to ten dual display spaces. Or I can separate the spaces, and get five on each screen.

I'd like to have ten independent spaces that aren't bound to a particular screen. e.g. Spotify usually lives on the right because it's secondary but I like to glance at it. If I'm working on a playlist, I'd like to bring its space to the left monitor. Can I do this without moving spotify to a different space?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?  Open Mission Control, then grab the space and drag it to its cousins on the other screen.

Answer (score 2):

System Preferences → Mission Control and enable **Displays have separate Spaces**.

[image: Mission Control Displays have separate Spaces]

Mission Control will show different Spaces on each monitor. To move a space between monitors with this enabled, open Mission Control and drag the space to your desired monitor.

Comment: Almost?  It's really opinionated about which spaces I can drag over.  Spaces with nothing, mail, or some terminals move.  Spaces with firefox and spotify don't.  I don't suppose there are any keyboard shortcuts or scripting options for managing this?

Comment: @valadil I’ve *never* had a space not be able to move to a different display. What exactly happens when you try?

Comment: The mouse moves to the other screen.  The space is left behind.  I tried going all the way to the far side of the screen.  My spotify one moves now, but the firefox one is still stuck.  It's desktop 1, just in case that one has special properties.

Comment: @valadil A display can’t have zero desktops, is this your problem? (Full screen apps do not count as desktops.)

Comment: Nope, I've got 4 on each.

Comment: Does this help?  http://www.giphy.com/gifs/3o7bu8u4qfRX8TOCu4

Comment: @valadil In that gif, you were trying to move Desktop 2, however that's your currently active desktop, shown by the blue border. You can't move the desktop you're currently on. Switch desktop and try again.